# Anyone Tried Mixing JavaFX and JRuby?

Tags: java, swing, jruby, javafx

Has anyone tried mixing `JavaFX` and `JRuby`?  I've built a JRuby desktop application with a Swing GUI (100% JRuby) and I'm toying with the idea of replacing the GUI with JavaFX for a more slick feel.

To fit with my current application, I want to implement an MVC pattern with the View being JavaFX and the Controller and Model being Ruby.

Comment: No idea, but even if this was possible, you might want to hold off. With Oracle's recent acquisition of Sun, a lot of people think they're going to let JavaFX die. Being a Java fanboi, I hope not :(

Comment: Eng.Fouad: I don't see any reason to mark "JavaFx" and "JRuby" as code. I'm also skeptical of the relevance of the tags [tag:java] and [tag:swing]; they are tangential (especially [tag:swing]). (I'm unable to undo the edit, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as conceptual differences between JavaFX Script,and J Ruby, there are quite a few. I'll start with JRuby. JRuby is not 
actually a language, per se. It is instead an implementation *in Java* 
of the Ruby programming language. The original runtime interpreter for 
Ruby was written in C (and perhaps some in C++, I'm not sure). The 
JRuby project was started by some guys who wanted a runtime 
implementation of Ruby that was written in Java instead.

Why? Well, there are some interesting advantages. First of all, they 
were able to make it very easy to invoke Java code from a Ruby 
application. Secondly, it means that Ruby programs end up being run by 
the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and therefore can benefit from all the 
optimization work that has been done on JVMs over the last ten years. 
Today JRuby functions as an interpreter only, but from what I heard from 
one of the project leads earlier this month, they are very close to 
being able to compile Ruby programs directly into JVM bytecode, which 
would provide another performance boost.

In the end, JRuby is very interesting for projects that are written in 
Ruby but that want to leverage either: existing Java libraries or 
existing Java runtimes (the JVM and even application/web servers like 
GlassFish and Tomcat) or both.

JavaFX on the other hand is scripting language which is directly injected for creating graphics kind of stuff.Very pragmatic too.So coming to usage when you are following a design pattern in this case MVC if you are following the rules it should be fine.But trust there
might be very few cases which may started using FX with JRuby.

Comment: You can learn about [JRuby](http://jruby.org) on the [JRuby project](http://jruby.org) page.  There is a nice presentation from Google IO on you tube too, that gets into the real power Ruby as a first class JVM language.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a [JRubyFX](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx) gem from the JRuby project for working with JavaFX 2.0. It supports both JavaFX in code and FXML. Most things should work, but it has a few issues that are documented in the Readme.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier when JavaFX 2.0 comes out.

Answer (score 1):

As of java 7u6 javafx is now part of the java language and available by default for Linux, Mac, and Windows.  You can program this with any language on the jvm so now you should be able to code your application very easily.

JavaFX script was dropped, but JavaFX the technology is bigger and better than ever.  Everything is now included in the API directly, so using Groovy or JRuby provide a great scripting framework for using JavaFX.

Happy Coding!